# CKeditor installation problems

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I installed first the module "npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-markdown-gfm" according to the documentation then the others.

Link to dosc https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/markdown.html

all modules have been installed using npm and when I try to use the code I get an error not found anyone know what could be the reason for this?

errors and code below

**my html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="editor">
    </textarea>


    <script type="module">
import { ClassicEditor } from '/ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic';

import { Bold, Italic } from '/ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles';
import { Essentials } from '/ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials';
// More imports.
// ...

import { Markdown } from '/ckeditor/ckeditor5-markdown-gfm';

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        plugins: [
            Markdown,
            Essentials,
            Bold,
            Italic,
            // More plugins.
            // ...
        ],
        // More of editor's configuration.
        // ...
    } )
    .then( /* ... */ )
    .catch( /* ... */ );


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**errors in conosle**

````
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
page:13 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
page:16 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
page:20 
        
        
       GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ckeditor/ckeditor5-markdown-gfm net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) ```
````